# Transferring to a new server/DNS...LOST

Tags: dns, whm, server.transfer

I must be missing something obvious here.

I have a client that currently does his hosting through Yahoo. I use WHM and have a reseller account through Hostgator. I set up a new account, and I put in the URL during the account creation process.

The problem is, it created everything properly, but everything points to the old URL, so nothing works.

For example, I installed Wordpress, and it looks for the .css file at "http://domainname.com/style.css", but that still points to the old location. If I go in an manually change it to "http://newIPaddress/style.css" it works.

Did I forget a step?

Answer (score 0):

I had to move WP installation once and I seem to remember running into similar problems.

I think it is because allot of references are stored in the database to the old domain.

There is a script here: http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ that will help fix this.

**But read the documentation bellow** there are some quirks involved.  I think this should help solve the problem you are experiencing though.

Documentation:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: I think i miss read, you a bit, there might still be a DNS problem.  Are you changing domains too, or just hosts?  Sometimes it can take some time for DNS changes to filter down.